# Making a console game. I want the game to end when they get 0 HP

Tags: c++

I am currently creating a game where it involves HP (character's health) and wanted to know how to make the game end when it reaches 0 HP for the player. Can anyone help me out? Also, my current code so far is pasted below if needed.

```
//Important:
//finalHp = hp - 10;
//cout << "Name: " << name << "   |   " << "Age: " << age << "   |   " << "Sex: " << sex << "   |   " << "Race: " << race << "   |   " << "HP: " << finalHp << endl;

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //sets strings and starting hp
    string name;
    string age;
    string sex;
    string race;
    string input;
    int hp = 20;

    //creating your character
    cout << "Welcome to xVert77x's first ever published game!\nWhen answering questions you must either capitalize the first letter not\ncapitalize anything at all and must spell things correctly.\n(This rule excludes your name. You can make your name\nXxXxsNipERkIll360n0Sc0peSkIllZxXxX.)\n\nHave Fun!\n" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a character name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "You have a very strange name... Enter a character age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Enter a character sex (M/F)(That means no aliens. Sorry ET): ";
    cin >> sex;
    cout << "Enter a character race (Human/Dwarf/Beast)(Still no aliens): ";
    cin >> race;
    cout << "Character created! Bringing you to your HUD..." << endl;

    //hud
    cout << "Name: " << name << "   |   " << "Age: " << age << "   |   " << "Sex: " << sex << "   |   " << "Race: " << race << "   |   " << "HP: " << hp << endl;

    //first question to player
    cout << "\nYou see a man. Do you kill him?\n1. Yes\n2. No" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "yes" || input == "Yes")
    //if they choose yes it will take 5HP
    {
        cout << "You killed him! You lost 5 HP in the battle.\nThere was no reward because you shouldn't\nkill helpless people. :(" << endl;
        hp -= 5;
        cout << "Name: " << name << "   |   " << "Age: " << age << "   |   " << "Sex: " << sex << "   |   " << "Race: " << race << "   |   " << "HP: " <<hp << endl;
    }
    //if they choose no it will do nothing
    else if (input == "no" || input == "No")
    {
        cout << "You decided otherwise. That was a very smart decision." << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << name << "   |   " << "Age: " << age << "   |   " << "Sex: " << sex << "   |   " << "Race: " << race << "   |   " << "HP: " << hp << endl;
    }

    //next question to the player
    cout << "\nYou come to a fork in the road. Do you go right or do you go left? " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "right" || input == "Right")
    //when they choose right this will happen
    {
        cout << "\nYou find a health potion and gain 7 HP!" << endl;
        hp += 7;
        cout << "Name: " << name << "   |   " << "Age: " << age << "   |   " << "Sex: " << sex << "   |   " << "Race: " << race << "   |   " << "HP: " << hp << endl;
    }
    //if you choose the left path
    else if (input == "left" || input == "Left")
    {
        cout << "\nYou fall into quicksand and barely make it out alive and then go to the path to the right. -10 HP." << endl;
        hp -= 10;
        cout << "Name: " << name << "   |   " << "Age: " << age << "   |   " << "Sex: " << sex << "   |   " << "Race: " << race << "   |   " << "HP: " << hp << endl;
    }


    cout << "\n\nEnd of game. For now... Press <enter> to exit...";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So how do you plan to change hp? 20-10 will never be zero.

Comment: You definitely need a loop for that, something like while(hp > 0) { … } or do { … } while(hp > 0);

Comment: My personal suggestion, if you want to make text based games don't use the console. Don't mistake text based games for being easy either. They are actually quite difficult to make, and using the console makes it more difficult. Use a library, it will make things much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `int main()` is setup in a way that exits at the very end, with that `return 0;` statement. Just like the rest of your `if (...)` branches, you check the current `hp` amount after you subtract some value. When that reaches (or falls below) zero, you can simply output a message and then (from your `main` function) exit (returning `0` inside of `main` effectively stops your program).

In general, the "has the player died yet?" check is going to be something you will do more than once, and the check itself (along with any kind of "you died" message) will be the same, regardless of where along the various `if ()` branches it actually occurred.

I'd create a new method like `bool isPlayerDead(int currentHP) { ... }` that you could call after each of your condition checks:

```
int main()
{
    // ...your setup stuff here...
    int hp = 20;

    // ...the first of your if() checks here...

    if (isPlayerDead(hp))
    {
        showPlayerDeathMessage();
        return 0;
    }

    // ...if you got here, the player is not yet dead... do some more if() checks...

    if (isPlayerDead(hp))
    {
        showPlayerDeathMessage();
        return 0;
    }

    // ...and again, player is not dead, so so some more...
    // (and repeat this process for a while...)


    // Finally, if you get here, the player did NOT die while playing. Maybe
    // print a "Wow! You're still alive!" message before exiting.
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you will organize this later to do loops, have more content, etc. but it seems like this should at least get you pointed in the right direction.